# salesforce custom fields text to integer

Tags: text, integer, salesforce

I have inserted data from a csv into a object. I have a column with both numbers and text and i need to do a calculation with this data. How do you convert text to integer using a custom field. So i want to do this if field = text do nothing else convert text to integer. Im doing this in the advanced formula in salesforce. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: So what does this have to do with programming? You might get more answers over on the Webmaster stack exchange site.

Comment: its the advanced formula which is code didn't know if there was a built in function to do this like cint()

Comment: Figured it out you use VALUE() to convert text to number

Comment: Although not technically programming, this is development related. Salesforce development involves both declarative work (formula fields etc.) and custom code. You rarely write any code without this kind of work first — it's akin to using the preprocessor in C in some ways.

Comment: i second what LaceySnr has to say here...

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with ISNUMBER:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNUMBER(YourCustomField__c), VALUE(YourCustomField__c) + 5, 'nothing')}"/>
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm